# Shirty birty (bertie)?

Tags: etymology, slang

I’ve been enjoying the BBC TV series *Last Tango in Halifax*, a show which regularly sends me to the dictionary in order to decipher certain inscrutable British-*isms*, the latest being “*don’t get all **shirty birty** (?) with me.*”

Oxford Dictionaries *online* defines [**shirty**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shirty) as an informal *adjective* which means: irritable; querulous, i.e., ‘*don’t get annoyed or **shirty** on the phone*’.

Etymonline has only this to say:
[**shirty**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=shirty&allowed_in_frame=0) *adjective*: "ill-tempered," 1846, slang, probably from shirt (n.) + -y (2), on notion of being disheveled in anger.

But where does **shirty** come from? And **berty** or **bertie**, is that merely decorative rhyming slang?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92713/meaning-and-origin-of-get-someones-shirt-out : *So what does all this shirt business have to do with being annoyed? A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English by Eric Partridge suggests that it comes from the custom of taking off one’s shirt before fighting. I wouldn't argue with that.*

Comment: I think that's it.  The jingle, Shirty-Bertie, makes a witticism of a criticism; especially as lots of these jingles come from baby-talk.

Comment: ***Dirty Birtie*** is one of those: http://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/gallery/2014/oct/28/how-to-draw-dirty-bertie-david-roberts

Comment: Neat example of cultural context Josh.  And for the linguistic side see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#Examples

Comment: Wild guess, but *shirty* reminds me of *snotty*, could the two be related? It also  reminds me of the the idiom [**keep your shirt on**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Keep+your+shirt+on!)

Comment: @Mari-Lou - I thought it's AmE equivalent might've been *shitty*, which is employed in approximately similar fashion. And *keep your shirt on* reminds me of another like expression which makes reference to a woman's undergarments, know what I mean? :-)

Comment: @Hugh - liked that poetic *witticism of a criticism* line, keep that stuff up. :-)

Comment: @Josh61 – that *Guardian* link would seem to indicate that though the *bertie* part of *shirty bertie* may have originated purely as a childish add-on rhyme, like *silly Billy*, it is now more than that: "*Are you a fan of the very naughty **Dirty Bertie**? Well say hello [to] David Roberts who invented him in the first place and wants to show you how to draw him. Bertie’s latest adventure **Dirty Bertie Horror!** is available from the Guardian bookshop, with pictures by David Roberts and words by Alan MacDonald.*"

Answer (score 2):

> But where does shirty come from? And berty or bertie, is that merely decorative rhyming slang?

1. Here's a question that deals well with the 'shirty' part. [Meaning and origin of “Get someone's shirt out”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92713/meaning-and-origin-of-get-someones-shirt-out)
2. Yes, in Britain and I imagine other places it is common (especially with children) to use mild insults that rhyme with a proper name, e.g. Silly Billy.
3. It's not rhyming slang. A suitable example of rhyming slang for 'shirty' might go as follows:

"No need to get Wooster about it."

The listener is supposed to recognise the well-known fictional character Bertie Wooster and then extract the rhyme from Bertie to make shirty.

Note that, as far as I know, that isn't currently used. It was made up by me as an illustration of how rhyming slang works.

Comment: Rather than [Cockney rhyming](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2014/jun/09/guide-to-cockney-rhyming-slang), which you correctly points out it doesn't belong, I think "shirty bertie" is a prime example of *reduplication* see: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/crisscross-dillydally-riffraff-etc/80550#80550. There's a wiki page on it too (as if Wiki wouldn't have one)

Comment: +1 thanks chasly, so then *bertie* is merely employed to blunt a caustic admonition (as in *silly Billy*) and adds no additional semantic information to the informal adjective *shirty*, correct?